# How to encode categorical data when 1+ categories are more relevant than others?

Tags: ordinal-data, categorical-encoding, association-rules

Suppose to have a questionnaire that asks 2 questions:

- "What is your top 3 favorite food?"
- "What drink do you like?"

**I need to find association between the 1st answer given and the 2nd.**

The first question however is ordered: a person says "1st pizza, 2nd apples, 3rd pasta".
Another person says "1st pasta, 2nd pizza, 3rd cake".

If the 1st question was unordered, I would just one-hot encode all the categories, and find association rules between X and y.

However, in the 1st question order matters, and I'm stuck here trying to figure out how to properly encode it or which test is best to use to answer my question (the one in bold).

One idea I had, was to do some kind of one-hot encoding but taking into account order: so that, if one person answers "1st pizza, 2nd cake, 3rd pasta", then for that row, pizza gets a score of 3, cake 2, pasta 1, everything else 0.

Then cluster my data based on the new columns and perform a Chi-squared test / Cramer V with respect to the answer given in the 2nd question.

I.E: population preference for "gin tonic" is 50%, but cluster 1, which has an average score for pizza of 2.5, only has 10% preference towards "gin tonic", then I can say (roughly) that people who like pizza a lot don't drink much gin-tonic.

But it feels iffy, and I'm not sure how to handle this.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.